# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment. How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm getting count of messages from json file, but i have an error... And i do not know why. In this program bot has to send information about member in mention. If I write `msg = None` at the beginning of the code, it won't send like `> messages = 10` it will send `messages = None`

***PROGRAM***

```
if args[0] == '!in':
    await client.delete_message(message)
    highclass = None
    gm = ""
    clan = None
    if (roleLeaders in message.author.roles or roleHunter in message.author.roles or roleDeputy in message.author.roles):
            for member in message.mentions:
                user = member
                userjoin = str(user.joined_at)
                joinpars= userjoin.split()
                join = joinpars[0]
                msg1 = user_get_msg(member.id)
                time1 = user_get_time(member.id)
                s = str(msg1)
                last = int(s[-1])
                st = str(time1)
                stm = time1 // 60
                sth = stm // 60
                std = sth // 24
                if time1 <= 60:
                    lastt = int(st[-1])
                    if lastt == 0:
                        time = '{0} секунд'.format(time1)
                    if lastt == 1 and not time1 == 11:
                        time = '{0} секунду'.format(time1)
                    if ((time1 >= 11 and time1 <= 19) or (lastt >= 5 and lastt <= 9)):
                        time = '{0} секунд'.format(time1)
                    if (lastt >= 2 and lastt <= 4) and not (time1 >= 11 and time1 <= 19):
                        time = '{0} секунды'.format(time1)

                if time1 <= 3600 and time1 > 60:
                    lastt = int(str(stm)[-1])
                    if lastt == 0:
                        time = '{0} минут'.format(stm)
                    if lastt == 1 and not stm == 11:
                        time = '{0} минуту'.format(stm)
                    if ((stm >= 11 and stm <= 19) or (lastt >= 5 and lastt <= 9)):
                        time = '{0} минут'.format(stm)
                    if (lastt >= 2 and lastt <= 4) and not (stm >= 11 and stm <= 19):
                        time = '{0} минуты'.format(stm)

                if time1 <= 86400 and time1 >3600:
                    lastt = int(str(sth)[-1])
                    if lastt == 0:
                        time = '{0} часов'.format(sth)
                    if lastt == 1 and not sth == 11:
                        time = '{0} час'.format(sth)
                    if ((sth >= 11 and sth <= 19) or (lastt >= 5 and lastt <= 9)):
                        time = '{0} часов'.format(sth)
                    if (lastt >= 2 and lastt <= 4) and not (sth >= 11 and sth <= 19):
                        time = '{0} часа'.format(sth)

                if time1 >= 86400:
                    lastt = int(str(std)[-1])
                    if lastt == 0:
                        time = '{0} дней'.format(std)
                    if lastt == 1 and not std == 11:
                        time = '{0} день'.format(std)
                    if ((std >= 11 and std <= 19) or (lastt >= 5 and lastt <= 9)):
                        time = '{0} дней'.format(std)
                    if (lastt >= 2 and lastt <= 4) and not (std >= 11 and std <= 19):
                        time = '{0} дня'.format(std)
                if msg1 >= 0:
                    if last == 0 or msg1 == 0:
                        msg = '{0} записок'.format(msg1)
                    if msg1 == 1 or (last == 1 and msg1 >= 21):
                        msg = '{0} записку'.format(msg1)
                    if (msg1 >= 2 and msg1 <= 4) or (msg1 >= 22 and msg1 <= 24):
                        msg = '{0} записки'.format(msg1)
                    if (last >= 5 and last <= 9):
                        msg = '{0} записок'.format(msg1)
                for role in member.roles:
                    with open('class.json', 'r') as roleread:
                        if role.id in roleread.read():
                            highclass = '<@&{0}>'.format(role.id)
                    with open('clans.json', 'r') as fp:
                        if role.id in fp.read():
                            gm = '> Является участником гильдии <@&{0}>.'.format(role.id)
                            if roleGM in member.roles:
                                gm = '> Является **мастером** гильдии <@&{0}>.'.format(role.id)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Персонаж {0}:\n'
                                                           '> Прибыл в город **{1}**;\n'
                                                           '> Принимал участие в жизни города **{2}**;\n'
                                                           '> Написал **{3}**;\n'
                                                           '> Имеет класс {4};\n'
                                                           '{5}'.format(member.mention, join, time, msg, highclass, gm))
```

***ERROR***

```
File "soul.py", line 497, in on_message
'{5}'.format(member.mention, join, time, msg, highclass, gm))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment
```

I've tried everything, what I could. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This can't be your actual code, because it raises `SyntaxError` before it even gets that far. Please give us a [mcve].

Comment: `msg1 >= 0:` would throw a SyntaxError so I'm not sure what code you're actually running here...

Comment: wait for a while

Comment: The problem is the `if` statements.  Because there's no `else` statement, it's possible for you to pass through that part of the code without assigning `msg` to anything.  Honestly, it looks like you're trying to do way too much all in one place.  Try breaking your code up into discrete functions (and coroutines where appropriate). That will make it easier to follow what you're doing.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'll  try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how you assign a value to `msg`:

```
if last == 0 or msg1 == 0:
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
if msg1 == 1 or (last == 1 and msg1 >= 21):
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
if (msg1 >= 2 and msg1 <= 4) or (msg1 >= 22 and msg1 <= 24):
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
if (last >= 5 and last <= 9):
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
```

So, what happens if, say, msg1 is some value in the range 10-20 (and last is not 0)? Then none of these `if`s will trigger. So `msg` will never get assigned anything. But you'll try to use it anyway, and get that error.

You probably want something like this:

```
if last == 0 or msg1 == 0:
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
elif msg1 == 1 or (last == 1 and msg1 >= 21):
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
elif (msg1 >= 2 and msg1 <= 4) or (msg1 >= 22 and msg1 <= 24):
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
elif (last >= 5 and last <= 9):
    msg = '{0} some useless tex'.format(msg1)
else:
    msg = '{0} WARNING! UNEXPECTED VALUE!'.format(msg1)
```

(Notice that changing all those `if`s to `elif`s could be a semantically meaningful change. If two conditions could both be true, your original code would execute both of them, so the second one would override what the first did, but the new code will only execute the first one. If it makes a difference, this is actually more often what you want—but if you wanted the other behavior, you may need to rewrite or reorder your conditions.)